# Eslint reports Flow Types as syntax error

Tags: javascript, eslint, flowtype

In cases where I'm using flow..
https://flowtype.org/

```
// @flow
var foo = (str: string) => {
  return str;
};
```

and Eslint together, 
Eslint reports unexpected token on `str: string`.

Is there a way to make Eslint ignore (or recognize) flow types and not report them as errors?

Comment: Look at [this](https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-flowtype)

Comment: @HamletHakobyan - spot on! Can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [Hamlet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/685467/hamlet-hakobyan) [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38819892/eslint-reports-flow-types-as-syntax-error#comment65006562_38819892) there is [eslint-plugin-flowtype](https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-flowtype) which will do a couple of things:

- Add syntax support for flow (and future JavaScript syntax) via [babel-eslint](https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint)
- Add additional eslint rules for linting flow syntax

Here are the [Installation Instructions](https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-flowtype#installation) and [Configuration docs](https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-flowtype#configuration).